# it will only do them harm

Tags: meaning

'Friends' he was saying ,'I've ordered brandy to be served to you all,so that we can celebrate my wedding properly'
No ,Frank don't give them brandy,begged Bathsheba,it will only ***do them harm***.
Far from the madding crowd,by Thomas Hardy

A)it will only do them harm.

B)it will only harm them.

is there any difference between the two sentences?

Comment: https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/do-them-harm-vs-harm-them.3710093/

Comment: The commenter at Word Reference said the two sentences mean the same, but both are incorrect. Maybe he likes brandy. In any case both forms mean the same thing.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty (Why do you say 'both are incorrect'? Bathsheba is warning her husband that brandy will not do the wedding guests any good.) Oh, I see - having read the Word Reference thread, I see the poster ignored the fact that it's part of a speech.

Comment: @KateBunting  I'm  sorry, what I wrote wasn't clear. The person who commented at wordreference said "both are incorrect"; I guessed that maybe he said so because he likes brandy. Of course, both sentences mean the same and are grammatically correct.

Answer (score 1):

Both *"it will only do them harm"* and *"it will only harm them"* are correct and idiomatic expressions; they also mean the same thing in this context. The only difference I can see is that in *"it will only **do** them **harm**"*, "harm" is a noun. In the other one (which you propose), "harm" is a verb.

I think the commentator at Word Reference made a typo when they said both were *incorrect*. Another answer in that forum emphasized how you should capitalize "**it**".

From Word Reference:

> ... but I will note that English sentences should begin with a capital letter. While I would say that both those sentences are grammatically correct, they should be written:
>
> A) **I**t will only do them harm.​
>   ​
>   B) **I**t will only harm them.​

This isn't correct in this case, because in this case, you have that part in quotations (which *you* have omitted for some reason; you have also omitted a comma and the exclamation mark). Basically, it is a dialogue. The following is the full sentence and in correct punctuation:

> 'No, Frank, don't give them brandy,' begged Bathsheba, 'it will only do them harm!'

That capitalization (i.e, the small letter "i") is correct. Note that the double quotation mark is often preferred over the single nowadays.

> “I hope,” she replied, “you aren’t referring to us.” — Chicago Manual of Style (17th ed.)